# How do Adobe PhoneGap and Apache Cordova differ?

Tags: cordova, mobile

So far, I haven't been able to find a "plain English" explanation of the difference between Apache Cordova and PhoneGap, and when to use either of them.

I'm looking to build an app with one of them, and I have the following constraints:

- It needs to be open source (preferably GPL, APL2, etc.)
- It needs to have a good dev community backing it (and preferably good docs)
- It needs to take the same javaScript and use it produce native binaries for Android, iOS, Windows Phone and Blackberry (write once, run anywhere)

If both these libraries/SDKs can accomplish these requirements, then how do I determine which project to go with? Is this a "Jenkins/Hudson" thing or are they really two separate projects? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I see this has received a closevote on account of not being constructive. I need to reiterate here: I am **not** asking "*Which is better, PhoneGap or Cordova*" with the intention of starting a Cordova/PhoneGap feud! I am simply asking for the technical differences between the two projects to help me reach a decision as to which to use. In other words, I'm not asking which is *better*: log4j or JCL, I am asking for the difference between log4j and JCL so I know which to go with.

Comment: See the wiki entry here: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/cordova/info

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Currently, the only difference is in the name of the download package and will remain so for some time.
>
> PhoneGap is a distribution of Apache Cordova. You can think of Apache Cordova as the engine that powers PhoneGap, similar to how WebKit is the engine that powers Chrome or Safari.

Source:
http://www.meetup.com/The-London-Dreamweaver-Meetup-Group/pages/Difference_between_Apachie_Cordova_and_Phone_Gap/

Moreover, PhoneGap meets all of the requirements you've specified.

Comment: This answer is inaccurate, Cordova is not an engine behind Phonegap.

Comment: there is one more Intel XDK (previously known as appmobi)..which supposedly make making phonegap apps even easier.

Answer (score 31):

PhoneGap was originally an open source project by Nitobi for packaging HTML5 code within native 'wrappers' for the creation of mobile applications. [Adobe acquired Nitobi](http://www.adobe.com/aboutadobe/pressroom/pressreleases/201110/AdobeAcquiresNitobi.html) and the PhoneGap technology. Adobe proceeded to contribute the PhoneGap code to the Apache Software Foundation in order to ensure that it remains open source. At this point the name was changed to Cordova, with Adobe maintaining the PhoneGap name and brand.

Adobe plans to add value to Cordova under the PhoneGap name, such as adding tool support and services such as [PhoneGap Build](https://build.phonegap.com/).

Currently many people still use the PhoneGap name to describe the open source framework (possibly because it is a better name!), but over time, this will probably change as Adobe builds on the PhoneGap brand and product range.

From a developer perspective, this is a pretty good situation, the framework remains open source, but if you want added value, you pay Adobe.

Comment: Phonegap is the same as Cordova in terms of the CLI. If you are not planning on using Phonegap Build, you can use either one of them. [LXJS Phonegap Workshop - Phonegap history](http://youtu.be/9GTqlwsTZ3g?t=5m).

Comment: I agree with givanse for the most part but as of version 3.5+ there do sadly seem to be some CLI differences between Cordova and PhoneGap. A couple examples:

1) The PhoneGap CLI seems to lack the "prepare" command which copies all needed files to the platform folders. The "build" command may do this though it seems like it doesn't (re)push the plugin files down(?). 

2) The Cordova CLI's "serve" command is not currently equivalent to the PhoneGap CLI's command of the same name (reference: http://goo.gl/qdzJfD)

Answer (score 5):

**History**

- Around 2009 - *Nitobi* creates PhoneGap framework.
- September 2011 -    Nitobi donates PhoneGap code to Apache Software
  Foundation.
- October 2011 - Nitobi announces that it has been acquired by Adobe.
  Adobe supports open sourcing PhoneGap’s code. Renaming the project
  has been suggested because of legal reasons.
- February 2012 - The project maintained by Apache is renamed
  “***Cordova***”, after Cordova Street in Vancouver where Nitobi had its
  office.

**Differences**

Apache Cordova is the core open source project where development and contributions happen.

Adobe PhoneGap is a distribution of Apache Cordova that additionally provides integration with Adobe’s utilities and services, e.g. PhoneGap Build.

Both Cordova and PhoneGap are extremely similar and their names are often used interchangeably. Apache Cordova receives updates slightly quicker, has a slightly simpler interface and lacks out-of-the-box integration with Adobe services.

**Which one to use?**

Are you going to use Adobe’s services? Pick Adobe’s PhoneGap. If not, Apache Cordova could be a better fit for you.