# Converting existing static website to an android app (APK) using phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, web, apk

I've a static website which purely uses only HTML5 and JS. And I have setup the phonegap in my windows 7 PC as well. My Question is what are the steps that I've to follow in order to create an android APK file out of the existing HTML/JS files. There are lot of tutorials on creating new phonegap project from the scratch. But I couldn't find any help on importing existing static website to phonegap project (please note that https://build.phonegap.com/apps is not an option for me.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> "And I have setup the phonegap in my windows 7 PC as well."

I'm assuming your CLI is ready for cordova development. Then it's enough to follow this [tutorial/documenation](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.5.0/guide_cli_index.md.html).

Go to your desired directory where you want to build your project. e.g.

```
d:
cd d:\myworks
```

Then create a cordova project

```
cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
```

go inside the project directory

```
cd hello
```

And platform android

```
cordova platform add android
```

There will be a `www` folder inside yourProject `hello->www`

Delete all css js html folders inside that directory and put your static pages there.

connect your device to PC and run `cordova run android`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've tried this solution it's working fine. And I've a small query. Is it a must to stick to the folder structure inside the www folder. is it ok if I keep all the css js and HTML resources inside my own folder?

Comment: you can use any structure inside that `www` folder. You can use your own folders, subfolders etc. BUT you need to keep the index.html file as it is now. just like `www->index.html` or you will need to change some settings.

Comment: that's really helpful thanks a lot again. last but not least, where exactly you can find the APK which I can used to copy to the actual device? is it in ..\platforms\android\ant-build ?

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20402818/build-android-release-apk-on-phonegap-3-x-cli