# How do I put my cordova application on the android play store?

Tags: android, cordova

If there is official cordova documentation for this, I couldn't find it and would appreciate a link.  I have run `cordova run android` to deploy to my phone.  Things look good.  Now I'm ready to turn this into an official app that users can download on the android play store?  When I build my app it generates a file named "CordovaApp-debug.apk".  That "debug" part makes me think this is the wrong file to work with, but I'm not sure how to generate the right file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20402818/build-android-release-apk-on-phonegap-3-x-cli

Hope to help you

Comment: @AndreasWeswaldi I'm hoping that will work, although the answer is a little dated and about PhoneGap as opposed to Cordova.  It will *probably* still work the same way, though.  Thanks

Comment: That question may be dated, but the information is still relevant.

Comment: you have sign in the apk inorder to release in play store

Comment: @sherb  Cool. I'll try it tomorrow.  Feel free to close this question.  I'm going to keep it around so the answer is easier to google.

Answer (score 19):

> Deploying a hybrid app to the Google Play Store

These steps would work for Cordova, PhoneGap or Ionic. The only difference would be, wherever a call to `cordova` is placed, replace it with `phonegap` or `ionic`, for your particular scenario.

Once you are done with the development and are ready to deploy, follow these steps:

1. Open a command line window (Terminal on macOS and Linux OR Command Prompt on Windows).
2. Head over to the /path/to/your/project/, which we would refer to as the Project Root.
3. While at the project root, remove the "Console" plugin from your set of plugins.
   The command is: `cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-console`
4. While still at the project root, use the cordova build command to create an APK for release distribution.
   The command is: `cordova build --release android`
5. The above process creates a file called `android-release-unsigned.apk` in the folder `ProjectRoot/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/`
6. Sign and align the APK using the instructions at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#signing-manually
   At the end of this step the APK which you get can be uploaded to the Play Store.

**Note:** As a newbie or a beginner, the last step may be a bit confusing as it was to me. One may run into a few issues and may have some questions as to what these commands are and where to find them.

**Q1. What are *jarsigner* and *keytool*?**
**Ans:** The Android App Signing instructions do tell you specifically what **jarsigner** and **keytool** are all about BUT it doesn't tell you where to find them if you run into a 'command not found error' on the command line window.
Thus, if you've got the Java Development Kit(JDK) added to your **PATH** variable, simply running the commands as in the Guide would work. BUT, if you don't have it in your PATH, you can always access them from the **bin** folder of your JDK installation.

**Q2. Where is *zipalign*?**
**Ans:** There is a high probability to not find the **zipalign** command and receive the 'command not found error'. You'd probably be googling **zipalign** and where to find it?
The **zipalign** utility is present within the Android SDK installation folder. On macOS, the default location is at, `user-name/Library/Android/sdk/`. If you head over to the folder you would find a bunch of other folders like `docs`, `platform-tools`, `build-tools`, `tools`, `add-ons`...
Open the `build-tools` folder. `cd build-tools`. In here, there would be a number of folders which are versioned according to the build tool-chain you are using in the Android SDK Manager. **ZipAlign** is available in each of these folders. I personally go for the folder with the latest version on it. Open Any.
On macOS or Linux you may have to use `./zipalign` rather than simply typing in `zipalign` as the documentation mentions. On Windows, `zipalign` is good enough.

Comment: The Android docs you reference no longer mention zipalign or jarsigner, but that page does mention keytool.

Comment: @Luke things might have changed over the past few years as I haven't been working on Cordova recently. I can probably look it up on the weekend or the near future and update my answer. Thank you for bringing this to my notice. :)