# How to build APK (signed) from hybrid app made in Framework7

Tags: build, apk, hybrid-mobile-app, html-framework-7

I've experience in building native android applications. But I'm completely new to hybrid application development and Would like to use [Framework7](http://framework7.io/docs/).

I'm starting to use it. I don't know how to build the project and get an install-able file (or for distribution in playstore).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can use cardova for developing app using framework7. or you can develop hybrid app using your native android app development tool with webview loading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cordova is a good way to start.

When I used to develop Hybrid apps, Cordova was the way to generate APKs.

I really enjoyed it, since it has a lot of Plugins, like FireBase Cloud Messaging Plugin to receive notifications within your hybrid App. It's more than a simple WebView App.

Apache Cordova is an open-source mobile development framework. It allows you to use standard web technologies - HTML5, CSS3, and JavaScript for cross-platform development. Applications execute within wrappers targeted to each platform, and rely on standards-compliant API bindings to access each device's capabilities such as sensors, data, network status, etc.

Use **Apache Cordova** if you are:

- a mobile developer and want to extend an application across more than
  one platform, without having to re-implement it with each platform's
  language and tool set.
- a web developer and want to deploy a web app that's packaged for
  distribution in various app store portals.
- a mobile developer interested in mixing native application components
  with a WebView (special browser window) that can access device-level 
  APIs, or if you want to develop a plugin interface between native and
  WebView components.

Here are all the steps needed to start with Cordova https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/index.html

Also, I used to follow these steps to generate a signed APK so it's possible to launch it on Google Play.
[How do I put my cordova application on the android play store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27435068/how-do-i-put-my-cordova-application-on-the-android-play-store)