# How to use cordova build --release to sign using existing eclipse generated keystore?

Tags: android, cordova, command-line, signing

Followed the steps by Steven Anderson here [Build android release apk on Phonegap 3.x CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20402818/build-android-release-apk-on-phonegap-3-x-cli/22979830#22979830)

I have an existing keystore created using eclipse for an Android cordova 2.4.0 project

I created the ant.properties file under /platforms/android with the following two entries

key.store=/Users/xxx/Documents/Android_Key_Store/myApp_Key_Store.keystore
key.alias=myApp

Now when I give **cordova build --release** command I only get android-release-unsigned.apk it is not prompting me to enter the password for my keystore

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Was this resolved? I too have same issue

Answer (score 1):

Also add:

```
key.store.password=KeystorePWD
key.alias.password=AliasPWD
```

Use the plain text version of each password.

Comment: same issue persists. Does it tell if I give wrong password or wrong path? Cause it seems the ant.properties file is getting ignored, every release build is a success irrespective of what I give in ant.properties. I installed ant using command brew install ant

Answer (score 0):

Following the steps mentioned in http://shallowsky.com/blog/programming/cordova-create-signed-app.html, was able to build signed apk in release mode.

Creating `release-signing.properties` was the important step. I use `cordova 5.4.1` version