# Cordova build --release gets Issue of type "ResAuto"

Tags: android, cordova, google-play, command-line-interface, keystore

I need the release apk because I am going to publish my app in google play now.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20402818/build-android-release-apk-on-phonegap-3-x-cli) it says, I just have to type "build --release" in the said path.

but my build fails and I get this error.

[image]

I don't really understand what it is saying about using http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto for the namespace =/

what am i supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `xmlns:app` value in scanner.xml with `http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto`
so it should looks like `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`