# Phonegap - Cordova export to android without debug

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

When i am making apk for google play, the result i have in the folder `\platforms\android\build\outputs\apk` is `apt-debug` which is not acceptable by google play.
How can i make production version of the app? Command line i am executing is `phonegap build android`.
I have searched for option in config.xml without success.
I am using Windows 10, x64. I have installed latest version of Java and Android studio, but i guess that is not important.
EDIT:
I am trying to add sign to released apk.

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore ProjectName.keystore -alias ProjectName -validity 1

jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore ProjectName.keystore android-release-unsigned.apk ProjectName

zipalign.exe -v 4 android-release-unsigned.apk.sig Release.apk
```

which give me this error: `Your APK cannot be analyzed using aapt. Error output`

Comment: you need to make release apk file top submit on store. apk-debug won't accept by apple store.. please go through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26449512/how-to-create-signed-apk-file-using-cordova-command-line-interface for make relase apk hope it will help

Comment: Thanks, trying to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is for Phonegap 3.0.x to 3.3.x. For PhoneGap 3.4.0 and higher see [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22979830/956397).

Found part of the answer [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/guide_platforms_android_tools.md.html#Android%20Command-line%20Tools), at Phonegap documentation. The full process is the following:

1. Open a command line window, and go to `/path/to/your/project/platforms/android/cordova`.
2. Run `build --release`. This creates an unsigned release APK at `/path/to/your/project/platforms/android/bin` folder, called YourAppName-release-unsigned.apk.
3. Sign and align the APK using the instructions at [android developer official docs](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html).

Thanks to @LaurieClark for the link (http://iphonedevlog.wordpress.com/2013/08/16/using-phonegap-3-0-cli-on-mac-osx-10-to-build-ios-and-android-projects/), and the blogger who post it, because that put me on the track.