# Cordova Vs PhoneGap for Sencha based Application

Tags: android, cordova, extjs, ios7

I have a Sencha application which i use to create iOS and Android apps. I have tried cordova but dont really understand why people prefer phonegap over cordova.
Enlightenment needed

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18174511/is-there-a-difference-between-phonegap-and-cordova-commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason to prefer phonegap is if you want to use phonegap build.
Project built using phonegap cli generates a config.xml using a different shema to handle specific PG build extensions.

Other benefit of phonegap can be if you want to use the [Phonegap developer app](http://phonegap.com/blog/2014/04/23/phonegap-developer-app/) (it may have changed but at the begining at least, it was supported only by the phonegap cli).

And there are also people using phonegap because at the begining there was only phonegap (before phonegap was renamed cordova) and most people continue to use the name phonegap for all cordova/phonegap stuffs.

Comment: To make it maybe clearer : phonegap is the original name of the project. Then Adobe took over and decided to split the project into a community-driven project (cordova) and their own flavour of the project that kept the original name. I don't think people "prefer" phonegap over cordova but they use phonegap or even use cordova and name it phonegap, because the historical name of the project is phonegap. I stopped using phonegap years ago but still always call cordova phonegap.