# Is phonegap and cordova the same

Tags: cordova

Say, most walkthroughs of Phonegap instruct starters to install both Phonegap and Cordova. whats the point downloading and installing both phonegap and cordova? Since phonegap is a distro of cordova why not just download and install one of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should have googeld first ->

[Phonegap / Cordova - the difference](http://phonegap.com/2012/03/19/phonegap-cordova-and-what%E2%80%99s-in-a-name/)

[Phonegap / COrdova - difference between commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18174511/is-there-a-difference-between-phonegap-and-cordova-commands)

Read that articles and i think, then anything should be clear.

You do not have to install BOTH (Phonegap AND Cordova) you have to choose one of that, and install just the one you want to.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have read those but the documentation does not specify, as per my question. But thanks for your response all the same.

Comment: Have you read my edit? You don't have to install both, you just have to install one. I'm using cordova, but thats everyones one choice :-)