# Phonegap cli, cordova and versions

Tags: cordova, lifecycle, cordova-cli

I was using cordova and pushing that to Phonegap build. It worked, allthough PGB told me I was using an old version - a setting there I couldnt change.

I've upgraded to Cordova 4 now, a version PGB apparently doesnt support.

So, they have different lifecycles ? Do they use the same version numbers at all ? Should we stop using cordova and start using the phonegap cli if we want to use Phonegap Build ?

Comment: I would say read this and it will answer your questions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18174511/is-there-a-difference-between-phonegap-and-cordova-commands

Comment: I started using cordova based on that post. That was perhaps a bad idea, seeing that i'm stuck with different versions now.

Comment: Oh I see, so you have two versions of a PhoneGap project and now you want to compile the latest one via PGB? right....Can you point out what special feature of v4 you are using. Otherwise why can't you make it on 3.6.3 that PhoneGap build support? I use 3.6.3 on PGB and it works fine even with custom plugins

Comment: actually there seem to be no features within the webapp that really conflict with PGB at this point. probably all changes are within platform assets. I was just confused about the situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cordova 4 is the version of the CLI, each platform has it's own version now. It seems that phonegap doesn't support choosing the version for each platform yet, so you have to choose a commom version for all of them (latest seems to be 3.6.3)

http://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2014/10/16/cordova-4.html

But yes, if you use phonegap build you should use phonegap CLI, not cordova CLI, as phonegap CLI allows you to push the app directly from the CLI

If you just upload your www folder to the phonegap build page, then it doesn't matter if you use cordova, phonegap or none at all, you just have to send the propper config.xml telling phonegap build which phonegap version to use

http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_preferences.md.html#Preferences