# Phone gap and cordova?

Tags: ios, cordova

I am planning to create a project in phonegap. But I am bit confused with the same. In phonegap website, when I checked the documentation, I could see two command, one is for cordova and the otherone is for phone gap. I have created the application with cordova command line tool. My client is clearly mentioned, he needs phonegap. But I have started with Cordova. So is it possible to integrate phone gap in my current project.

Comment: PhoneGap is an open source distribution of Cordova. Both are same:http://phonegap.com/about/faq/

Answer (score 0):

See this link it will be clear [PhoneGap, Cordova, and what’s in a name?](http://phonegap.com/2012/03/19/phonegap-cordova-and-what%E2%80%99s-in-a-name/)

> PhoneGap is a distribution of Apache Cordova. You can think of Apache
> Cordova as the engine that powers PhoneGap, similar to how WebKit is
> the engine that powers Chrome or Safari. (Browser geeks, please allow
> me the affordance of this analogy and I’ll buy you a beer later.)
>
> Currently, the only difference is in the name of the download package and will remain so for some time.

Look at this [answer from Avhishek where there is more details about how they differ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18174657/604097)

So it doesn't actually matter much which command you are using. You can use cordova instead of phonegap..Phonegap is build on top of cordova.

Look at both documentation ([phonegap](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/guide_cli_index.md.html) & [Cordova](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html)) they are quite same.