# How to display logout alert box in ios mobile application

Tags: android, angularjs, mobile-application, phonegap

I am running this using phonegap. When i run in Android the logout box is correct and its showing "confirm" as title in the logout box. Even in ios everything is perfect but the logout box shows title as "index.html"(which is the current page name)

```
                         $rootScope.logout=function()
                        {

                  response=confirm(GetLocalString("HMLOGOUTMSG",_language));
                            if(response==true)
                            {
                                logout();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                menuchk();
                            }
                        }
```

I dont want the title as "index.html". Can you suggest a method to not display the title as "index.html"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ios PhoneGap pages will show the page name in alert, you need to use a plugin for notification.
To add the plugin run this code.

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-dialogs
```

Usage

```
navigator.notification.confirm(message, confirmCallback, [title], [buttonLabels])
```

- **message**: Dialog message. (String)
- **confirmCallback**: Callback to invoke with index of button pressed (1,
  2, or 3) or when the dialog is dismissed without a button press (0).
  (Function)
- **title**: Dialog title. (String) (Optional, defaults to Confirm)
- **buttonLabels**: Array of strings specifying button labels. (Array)
  (Optional, defaults to [OK,Cancel])

Example

```
function onConfirm(buttonIndex) {
    alert('You selected button ' + buttonIndex);
}

navigator.notification.confirm(
    'You are the winner!', // message
     onConfirm,            // callback to invoke with index of button pressed
    'Game Over',           // title
    ['Restart','Exit']     // buttonLabels
);
```

The callback takes the argument buttonIndex (Number), which is the index of the pressed button. Note that the index uses one-based indexing, so the value is 1, 2, 3, etc.

[Documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-dialogs/#navigatornotificationconfirm)

Now its working fine,

```
$rootScope.logout = function () {
    function onConfirm(buttonIndex) {
        if (buttonIndex == 1) {
            logoutfunc();
        }
        else {
            menuopenchk();
        }
    }

    navigator.notification.confirm(
        'Are you sure to logout?',
        onConfirm,
        'Logout',
        ['Yes', 'Not Now']
    );
}
```

Comment: cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-dialogs , Is it cordova plugin or phonegap plugin in the start

Comment: @AmruthaJRaj I didn't understand what u mean in comment

Comment: is it like  
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-dialogs or phonegap plugin add cordova-plugin-dialogs

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38526720/how-to-use-cordova-plugins-with-phonegap-cli, just read this

Comment: @AmruthaJRaj phonegap plugin add cordova-plugin-dialogs --save,

Comment: Ok, What are the values returned by confirmCallback?

Comment: @AmruthaJRaj i am updated the answer, pls check, or you can check documentation from the above link

Comment: if(buttonIndex==1)
                                {
                                    logoutfunc();
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    menuopenchk();
                                } I have tried but logout function is not working properly.

Comment: @AmruthaJRaj How can I see your code, I there any way

Comment: @AmruthaJRaj do you have anydesk (Screen sharing application)

Comment: Just view the answer, I have extended it

Comment: @AmruthaJRaj answer or question, i can't see any changes

Comment: @AmruthaJRaj Can you pls log the buttonIndex value in callback

Comment: Pls log the value of buttonIndex in your callback function

Comment: navigator.notification.confirm(
                                              'Are you sure to logout?', 
                                               onConfirm(buttonIndex),            
                                              'Logout',           
                                              ['Yes','Not Now']     
                                                    ); Is it like this??

Comment: Can you ping me in this mail id jihinraju@gmail.com, this very default to chat here, if it possible

Comment: Ok, if you have any doubts or problem in angular you can ping me in above mail id, and don't forget to accept my answer

Comment: Okie Thank you sure. :]