# Cordova and phone gap development

Tags: android, cordova

I am newbie in mobile development and I try to run instances locally.

I try to understand how native frameworks work.

I found phonegap as a native framework. If I go to their site in order to [download](http://phonegap.com/install/) it I can download the latest version.

However also I found the apache cordova which is the same with phonegap?

What are the difference and which one I can use?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do Adobe PhoneGap and Apache Cordova differ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12318424/how-do-adobe-phonegap-and-apache-cordova-differ)

Comment: @Adam Stelmazczyk. Thank but it is from 2012. So if I use apache cordova it is the same as the phonegap download? Why they still have updates for phonegap?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt your inferences.

Phonegap is a framework that allows you to code mobile apps using languages commonly know for web development (HTML, CSS, JS, Jquery etc).

Apache Cordova is the engine that renders this source code to app format application file with file extensions that runs for Andriod or iOS or other platforms.

So you can have one source code and generate apps for every platform.

You need both Phonegap and Apache Cordova for this.

Comment: But the tutorials I found on youtube are different for phonegap and apache cordova.

Comment: Nope, you dont need both Cordova and PhoneGap to do this. PhoneGap is built on top of Cordova to provide extra functionality.

Comment: So if I want to build native apps I should use cordova?

Comment: no, cordova isn't the engine that renders the source code